# Bootstrap 4 Navbar has zero height on smaller viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Link to demo on codeply https://www.codeply.com/go/3HkzkLKpow

Here are a selection of Navbars produced by Skelly. I have copied navbar 10 and placed it second in line. When you resize the viewport so as to get the toggle visible the navbar in position 2 and 11 loses its height. The toggle is just visible and clickable and produces a div within the viewport perfectly. Is this an issue with bootstrap 4? I am aware that I could use a stylesheet to address the issue but should not need to.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does this because the `.navbar-toggler-right` is positioned absolutely to the right, which takes it out of the flow of the relative container. The `.navbar` has padding, which is why the black bar is still shown partly. If you change the `.container` to a container fluid and position the `.navbar-toggler-right` relatively and float it right, the menu will be placed in the same position, but the bar won't be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the input but why do all the other navbars work without additional coding and this doesn't? Surely this should be taken care of in the css supplied with Bootstrap

Comment: It's the `.navbar-toggler-right` class that has it. If you don't want it, take it off. Add the class `.pull-right` to it instead and it will have a similar effect. The other ones in the rest of the example are actually the same way, but they have the Brand in the navigation, which is making it stay the proper height because Brand is still within the flow of the page.

Comment: Thanks - took out the .navbar-toggler-right and added the pull right and it worked nicely. Need to go away and work through exactly how all these positioning elements fit together.